# How to set Oracle Procedure to Dto with MyBatis

Tags: oracle, mybatis

how can I get the following attributes of a stored procedure performed in oracle, I need to obtain cursor, p_message, p_error_id in mybatis xml with spring??????

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG
AS
    PROCEDURE GET_TRACKING(fecha in varchar2, registros in number, p_mensaje out varchar2, p_error_id out number, p_list out SYS_REFCURSOR) is
    BEGIN
         BEGIN
             OPEN p_list FOR
             SELECT * FROM TRACKING;

             p_error_id := 1;
             p_mensaje  := 'OK';
         EXCEPTION
             when others then
                  p_error_id := -1;
                  p_mensaje  := substr(sqlerrm, 1, 100);

         END;
    END;
END;
```

In java jdbc, this is the code:

```
public int insertProcess(String processName, String processType, Response response) {
        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            Utils.loguea("Parametros de salida insertProcess processName  = " + processName + " processType = " + processType, "info");
            String statement = null;
            StringBuilder qryBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            qryBuffer.append("BEGIN ");
            qryBuffer.append(this.schema);
            qryBuffer.append(".GET_TRACKING(?, ?, ?, ?, ?); END;");

            statement = qryBuffer.toString();

            conn = this.dataSourceConector.getDataSource().getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareCall(statement);
            stmt.setString(1, processName);
            stmt.setString(2, processType);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            stmt.execute();
            int process_id = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getInt(3);
            int error_id = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getInt(4);
            String mensaje = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getString(5);
            if (response != null) {
                response.setErrorID(error_id);
                response.setMensaje(mensaje);
            }

            Utils.loguea("Parametros de salida insertProcess error_id  = " + error_id + " mensaje = " + mensaje, "info");
            return process_id;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Utils.logueaException("Error en método insertProcess ", ex);
            if (response != null) {
                response.setErrorID(-1);
                response.setMensaje(ex.getMessage());
            }
            return -1;
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Utils.logueaException("Error al cerrar CallableStatement en método insertProcess", ex);
                }
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Utils.logueaException("Error al cerrar Connection en método insertProcess", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In java code is like this, but in mybatis i need help for obtain p_error_id, p_message and the cursor, please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyBatis annotations to call Stored Procedure and get Out Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910795/mybatis-annotations-to-call-stored-procedure-and-get-out-params)